# Finding and Concatenating strings

Tags: regex, perl, replace, preg-replace

I want to find some punctuation characters and concatenate them with spaces.

For example:
If any punctuation are found then I want to add spaces to front and end of them.

```
$line =~ s/[?%&!,.%*\[◦\]\\;@<>{}#^=\+()\$]/" $1 "/g  ;
```

I tried using `$` as used in Php where we can use `$1`, but it didn't work.
I searched on the web and couldn't find the Perl syntax?

Additionally, how can I preserve `...` as a single token?

What is the true syntax for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround match pattern with `()` to capture it into `$1`

```
$line =~ s/([?%&!,.%*\[◦\]\\;@<>{}#^=\+\(\)\$])/ $1 /g;
```

**EDIT** *(as per OP's comment)*

> how can i preserve '...' a single token ?

One way would be to revert back the changes for that token.

```
$line =~ s/ \.  \.  \. /.../g;
```

Comment: thanks for solutions, then how can i preserve '...' a single token ? – @jkshah

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan Please check EDIT in my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

my $string = "For example; If i found any puncs. above list, i want to add spaces to front and end of token.";

$string =~ s/([[:punct:]])/ $1 /g;

print "$string\n";
```

Outputs:

```
For example ;  If i found any puncs .  above list ,  i want to add spaces to front and end of token .
```

- Obviously, if you want your output different from above, you can just add it in-between `/ /` - I've just replaced all punctuation with " punctuation ".

Comment: Your substitute removes the punctuation.

Comment: Misunderstood the question - have now fixed to replace any punctuation with `" punctuation "`

Comment: thanks for solutions, then how can i preserve '...' a single token ?